# Recursion running really slow - AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, recursion, android-asynctask, ram

I'm trying to make a TicTacToe game where the computer trys to win and not lose - it partially works but the code runs really slowly on Android but fine on a computer.

The computer's decision is made in an `AsynTask` and the `doInBackground` calls a UI method.

I keep getting:

`D/dalvikvm(14142): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1924K, 15% free 26534K/30996K, paused 2ms+11ms, total 136ms`

and

`D/dalvikvm(14142): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1711K, 12% free 24208K/27304K, paused 106ms, total 106ms`

Here's the code  or here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xf6dd2mlkqw2rmr/OnePlayer.java

```
    public class ComputerTurn extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public Context activity;

    public ComputerTurn(Context a)
    {
        this.activity = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(OnePlayer.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Process Description Text", true);
    };      
    long interval =0;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        Date interestingDate = new Date();
        ((OnePlayer) activity).ComputerPromptInputandSet(current_player);
        interval = (new Date()).getTime() - interestingDate.getTime();
        System.out.println("Time: " +interval);
        return null;
    }       

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OnePlayer.this);
        builder.setMessage("Time: " +interval)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //  do things

                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        //progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

`ComputerPromptInputandSet:`

```
void ComputerPromptInputandSet(int current_player) {
    //task.doProgress(1);
    depth = 0;
    System.out.println("Computer turn");
    bestMoves = new ArrayList<String>();
    drawMoves = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i <3; i++){
        for(int j =0; j <3; j++){
                if(board[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("-") 
                  && !board[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("O") 
                  && !board[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("X")){
                    CompNode currentNode = null;
                    String [][] temp = board;
                    depth = 0;
                    System.out.println("Calling AI");
                    AI(i, j, currentNode, temp, 0);
                    board[i][j]="-";
                    //print(board);
                    //System.exit(0);
             }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("depth of win: " + bestwin_depth);
    System.out.println("depth of draw: " + bestdraw_depth);
    System.out.println("depth of lose: " + bestlose_depth);

    System.out.println("bestwin: " + bestwin);
    System.out.println("bestdraw: " + bestdraw);
    System.out.println("bestlose: " + bestlose);
    WINNER_FOUND = false;
    game_winner = false;
    is_draw = false;

}
```

`AI:`

```
void AI(int i, int j, CompNode cNode, String [][] fake, int depth){
    //task.doProgress(1);
    depth++;
    //System.out.println("In AI");
    //System.out.println("Depth: "+ depth);
    fake[i][j] =  getLetter(current_player); 
    //print(fake);
    boolean winner = CheckWinner(1, fake);
    if(winner){
        //System.out.println("Winner move found");
        //print(fake);
        //cNode.value= 1000;
        if(bestwin_depth >= depth){
            bestwin_depth = depth;
            bestwin = i+"/"+j;
        }
        bestMoves.add(i+"/"+j);
        WINNER_FOUND = false;
        game_winner = false;
        is_draw = false;
        return;
    }
    if(is_draw == true){
        //System.out.println("Draw found or no more space");
        drawMoves.add(i+"/"+j);
        WINNER_FOUND = false;
        game_winner = false;
        is_draw = false;
        return;
    }

    /*  check if game over on move
        if over 
            return
        if not over for comp

    */ 
    ArrayList<String> indexes = getLegalMoves(fake);
    //System.out.println("Legal Moves: "+ indexes.size());
    if(indexes.size() ==0){
        //System.out.println("Draw found or no more space");
        if(bestdraw_depth >= depth){
            bestdraw_depth = depth;
            bestdraw = i+"/"+j;
        }   
        drawMoves.add(i+"/"+j);
        return;
    }
    //permute (indexes, 0, i, j, cNode, fake);
    cNode = new CompNode(indexes.size(), i , j);

    Iterator sets = indexes.iterator();
    PlayerNode [] possibleMove = cNode.children;
    int k =0;


    while (sets.hasNext() ) {
        String index = (String) sets.next();

        String [] index_ =  index.split("/");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(index_[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(index_[1]);

        //System.out.println("( "+x + ", " +y + " )");
        possibleMove[k] = new PlayerNode(indexes.size()-1, x, y);
        String [][]temp = fake;
        playerMove(x, y , possibleMove[k], temp, depth);
        //depth--;

        fake[x][y] = "-";
        k++;
    }
    //System.exit(0);
}
```

`playerMove:`

```
void playerMove(int i, int j, PlayerNode pNode, String [][]fake, int depth){
    //task.doProgress(1);
    depth++;
    //System.out.println("In playMove");
    //System.out.println("Player move: ");
    //System.out.println("Depth: "+ depth);
    fake[i][j] =  getOtherLetter(current_player); 
    //print(fake);

    boolean winner = CheckWinner(0, fake);
    pNode = new PlayerNode(0, 0, 0);
    if(winner){
        //System.out.println("Player winning move");
        if(bestlose_depth >= depth){
            bestlose_depth = depth;
            bestlose = i+"/"+j;
        } 
       // pNode.value= -1000;
        WINNER_FOUND = false;
        game_winner = false;
        is_draw = false;
        return;
    }
    if(is_draw == true){
        //System.out.println("Draw found or no more space");
        drawMoves.add(i+"/"+j);
        WINNER_FOUND = false;
        game_winner = false;
        is_draw = false;
        return;
    }

    ArrayList<String> indexes = getLegalMoves(fake);
    //System.out.println("Legal Moves: "+ indexes.size());
    if(indexes.size() ==0){
        //System.out.println("Draw found or no more space");
        if(bestdraw_depth >= depth){
            bestdraw_depth = depth;
            bestdraw = i+"/"+j;
        } 

        drawMoves.add(i+"/"+j);
        return;
    }
    //permutePlayer (indexes, 0, i, j, pNode, fake);
    pNode = new PlayerNode(indexes.size(), i , j);

    Iterator sets = indexes.iterator();
    CompNode [] possibleMove = pNode.children;
    int k =0;


    while (sets.hasNext() ) {
        String index = (String) sets.next();

        String [] index_ =  index.split("/");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(index_[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(index_[1]);

        //System.out.println("( "+x + ", " +y + " )");
        possibleMove[k] = new CompNode(indexes.size()-1, x, y);
        String [][] temp = fake;
        AI(x, y , possibleMove[k], temp, depth);
        //depth--;
        fake[x][y] = "-";
        k++;
    }
    //System.exit(0);
}
```

PlayerNode Class

```
class PlayerNode {
    CompNode [] children;

    PlayerNode(int num, int i , int j){
    this.children = new CompNode[num];
    }
}
```

CompNode Class:

```
class CompNode {
    PlayerNode [] children;

    CompNode(int num, int i, int j){
        this.children = new PlayerNode[num];
    }
}
```

The `ComputerPromptInputandSet` take 52 secs to run on my phone, 2 mins on the emulator and 34 secs on another phone.

Here's the stats screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Am i correct that you computer is about 500 times faster then your phone? That might well be normal, maybe due to limited mobile memory which will invoke the garbage collector much more often.

General optimisations should fix the problem.

The code is quite complex and i'm not really understanding it but if the getLegalMoves method does what i think you should be able to optimise it enormously by returning less possible moves by eliminating moves that have already a players cross in the same x and y axis and in the diagonals.

Comment: There's also a considerable potential in simple improvements like using a char[][] for the board instead of a String[][]. Also, a move can be encoded in a single int (using row<<2+col) to avoid split, String[] and parseInt.

Comment: Or even Boolean[][] for that matter (null is no marking whereas true is O and false is X).